# SQL 2014 not recognizing Backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am having a problem on two different servers, both are running sql 2014.  The maintenance plan does not delete the older backups.  I have checked the permissions and the formatting and everything is correct.  During troubleshooting I ran the xp_delete_file command to delete a single backup file.  I got the error "Error executing xp_delete_file extended stored procedure: Specified file is not a SQL Server backup file." I ran a manual full backup and tried it again on that new backup file and received the same error.

I then copied a couple of the older transaction log files to a different server that was working correctly, ran the same script on them and the files were deleted.

Is there any way to force sql to recognize the backups that it makes as sql backups?  The files are good, account used is sysadmin account, and file permissions are not the problem.

Comment: Are you specifying the proper parameters, [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582996/sql-server-xp-delete-file-parameters)? Are you using an unusual backup extension? Are these native SQL backups, or are you backing up using 3rd-party software?

Comment: the paramaters are correct.  Using bak and trn as the backup extensions and these are native sql backups created with sql server management studio.  The problem is that sql doesn't recognize the backups as sql backups on these two servers.

Comment: Restore Headeronly on those same files completes successfully.

Comment: @Chris - can you update your question and post the command you used for xp_delete_file?

Comment: @Chris - Have you granted _BOTH_ the SQL Server Service Account _AND_ the SQL Agent Service Account (_if different_) read/write/delete authority on the backup folder?

Comment: This xp is undocumented, unsupported, and many people have reported issues with it deleting nothing, not enough, or too much. Have you considered just letting SQL Server do backups and deal with file cleanup separately (using Powershell, for example)?

Comment: Scripts used are:  EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\',N'bak',N'2017-12-28T14:32:33',1
completes successfully, but nothing is deleted and EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup.bak' which gives the error that the file is not a sql backup.

Comment: Aaron, our company would prefer not to use a seperate cleanup utility just in case something happens and the full backup does not run successfully.  I would hate to log into this server after a crash and see that all of the backups were deleted.  In the maintenance plan, cleanup only occurs after a successful full backup.

Comment: the sql server service account is localsystem and the agent account has been changed to one of the domain admin accounts for testing purposes.  Both have full permission to the files and folders.

Comment: @Chris As with any good maintenance, the logic can easily be built in to only delete backups files more than n days old. Hopefully your backup process has enough smarts to let you know it's failing before it's been failing for n days. I just don't think there's any good reason to have SQL Server be involved in keeping your disk clean. If disk space is an issue, the solution is simple: buy more disk. You've already spent more salary looking into this issue than it would have cost to buy 10X more space.

Comment: Aaron, we have the logic built into the maintenance plan to not delete any sql backups unless there is a good full backup.  On these two, disk space isn't really a concern as one customer has over a year of full,diff, and trn backups still on the server.  The problem is that eventually it will fill up.  This is a free service that our company provides to our customers that aren't big enough to have dbas so we can't buy more disk space for them.  The issue is that the sql cleanup is not recognizing the backups as valid backup files.